# After installing Win7 on my laptop I'm having trouble extending the desktop to an external monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a HP TX2000 laptop and a HP w2408 screen. Yesterday, I installed Win7 and I'm having trouble having the 24 inches screen work as a secondary screen. It seems like my laptop cannot detect both screens (its own and the 24 inches one).

I think I already have all the drivers installed (I ran Win7's tool to detect and automatically update drivers and it said everything was up to date!), so what might be the problem?

If I connect the 24 inch screen to my laptop, it will happily show a copy of what is being shown on that big screen too, but I'd like to have it ''extend'' the desktop to the big screen, instead.

Comment: Do you have an NVidia card or the integrated graphics? You might want to try setting up the displays either through the Nvidia utility or the Intel utility, just to see if it works. I had some problems with my latitude, it was showing 4-5 monitors in the windows display properties, but the Intel utility worked fine.

Comment: Please, answer Kyle's question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the HP site and check for drivers there. Windows update is not always "correct" in picking drivers. I don't think there are Windows 7 drivers there but Vista drivers that may do the trick. There may be a driver from the card maker but some OEMs do things a bit different with the chipset and the driver gives issues. There may alos be an app that HP provides that manages the desktop/display but it is usually in the driver package.

Comment: I already tried installing them, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried using `Windows` + `P`? If you hold down the `Windows` key and press `P` several times, you can tab between the different options. Choose `Extend` (which is the third option).